# Using Network Render on different Blender version

Tags: rendering, network

I've trying to use Blender 2.79b on my Client machine, and Blender 2.79.1 on my Slave machines. I want to do that because Blender 2.79.1 could use both CPU and GPU to render at the same time so it render faster than Blender 2.79.
But when I setup Client and Slaves like that, my network doesn't recognize the Slaves. My result after many try are:

1. Client using 2.79b, Slaves Using 2.79b - **WORK**
2. Client using 2.79.1, Slaves Using 2.79.1 - **DIDN'T WORK**
3. Client using 2.79b, Slaves Using 2.79.1 - **DIDN'T WORK**

Please tell me is it possible to run render network like that, or is there a better way for my situation?   Thank you for taking your time on my question.